# How to represent a bivector/bi-covector or more complex tensors (of rank 1,2/2,1/2,2 or even higher) using numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, tensor-rank

If I understand correctly, the rank 0,0 tensor is just a scalar, rank 0,1 tensor is a vector represented as a column, rank 1,0 is a covector represented as a row, rank 1,1 is a linear transformation represented as a matrix. However, if the linear transformation is represented as a two-dimensional array m * n, then I have no idea how to represent, say, a bivector (or tri- and higher rank) in numerical form, nothing comes to my mind, except as other two-dimensional arrays.

Comment: First of all, what do you call a bivector? A tensor if rank 0,2? Then, it is represented again with a matrix, which is understood to have a different meaning compared to linear transformations.

Comment: b i l i n e a r i t y, is the mechanism for rank two tensors